# How do I generate protobuf java files resolved for the correct package name?

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am using the protobuf gradle plugin (https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) to generate .java files from protbufs made by a different team at my company.

My setup looks like so

```
protobuf {
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/main/java"

    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${LibraryVersion.PROTOC}"
    }
    plugins {
        id("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${LibraryVersion.GRPC_PROTOBUF}"
        }
    }
}
```

The files generate successfully under the directory structure like so:

```
root
   protobuf
      protobuf-files
      build.gradle.kts
      src
         main
            java
               main
                  java
                     com
                        companyname
                           protobuf
```

The files are generated with the package name of
`package com.companyname.protobuf.reader;`. Basically everything in /src is auto generated using the config I listed above.

The problem is that when I use these files in code like so

```
import com.companyname.protobuf.reader.SomeClass1
import com.companyname.protobuf.reader.SomeClass
import com.companyname.protobuf.reader.SomeOtherClass
import com.companyname.protobuf.reader.ClassClassClass

typealias TestID = com.companyname.protobuf.someclass.UUID128

abstract class CentralManager {
```

I can build the project fine, and it even works correctly. The issue is that because the package name is different, my IDE fails to resolve it, and it highlights all of the protobuf items in red, even though I can build and run everything just fine.

I see `Unresolved reference: protobuf`

Unfortunately, the protobufs themselves specify a package like `package me.company.protobuf.reader;` and I am not able to change this, as it comes from a different team that controls this.

The error I see in the actual generated protobuf file is

```
Package name 'com.companyname.protobuf.reader' does not correspond to the file path 'main.java.com.companyname.protobuf.reader'
```

I understand what the error means, but I am not quite sure how to fix it. Any tips are appreciated. I cannot just simply move the files, as they are auto generated. I need to have them generate at a correct path, or create a way for the IDE to correctly match the files to their actual package location.